# HTML Dropdown list with user input field

Tags: html, forms, html-select

I have a dropdown list as follows..

```
<select name="school"><option value="None" selected>None</option>
<option value="DeSoto">DeSoto</option>
<option value="Hillsboro">Hillsboro</option>
<option value="Grandview">Grandview</option>
<option value="Festus">Festus</option>
<option value="R-7">R-7</option>
<option value="Home-Schooled">Home-Schooled</option>
```

If the contact being entered in the database happens to live in a school district not listed in the dropdown list, the data entry person would have to add a school to the database.  How can I add a selection to the end of the list that would allow the end user to enter a school name.

I can handle the PHP code to process the entry, I just need some ideas on how to accomplish either turning the dropdown list into a user input field, or some other solution.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: JavaScript will help you do it.

Comment: Lots of ways to do it, none are simple, depends on your needs. Most solutions consist of not using a <select> , but a regular input field that displays a custom made popup when you click inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here its something like that:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#addSchool").click(function(){
    $("#schoolContainer").append('<option value="' + $("#newSchool").val() + '">' + $("#newSchool").val() + '</option>');
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="school" id="schoolContainer">
    <option value="None" selected>None</option>
    <option value="DeSoto">DeSoto</option>
    <option value="Hillsboro">Hillsboro</option>
    <option value="Grandview">Grandview</option>
    <option value="Festus">Festus</option>
    <option value="R-7">R-7</option>
    <option value="Home-Schooled">Home-Schooled</option>
</select>
    
    <input type="text" id="newSchool"/>
    <input type="button" id="addSchool" value="Insert"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/damian_silvera/NcpKp/

Comment: Need some explanation, the jsfiddle adds options to the select, which is not what the OP wants

Comment: The ajax call to insert data inside database must be inside the click function (before or after the append) but the code in the .php file can be implemented in many different ways, thats why i didn't explain nothing about it...

Comment: Sounds like the OP wants to be able to free text into the field if the option is not in the drop down. Adding it to the list in the dropdown would be done on the server and would only show up after the page was reloaded.

Comment: This actually works well.  Thank you.  I've applied this to my application and I think this will suit my needs without requiring me to write a bunch of code to add a new school to the database when it's entered in a text box.  This way I can keep the most used schools in the dropdown, and on the occasion that a new school has to be used the data entry person can input that field and add it to the dropdown as necessary.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a combo box : Input+Dropdown list.

http://javascript.about.com/library/blcombo.htm

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/P39W5/

**OR** you can dynamically add a input box:

http://jsfiddle.net/EMEVL/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#newSchool').hide();
    $("#schoolContainer").change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();      
        if (val == 'Other School') {
            $('#newSchool').show();
        } else {
            $('#newSchool').hide();
        }
    }).change();
});
```

HTML:

```
School: <select name="school" id="schoolContainer">
    <option value="None" selected>None</option>
    <option value="DeSoto">DeSoto</option>
    <option value="Hillsboro">Hillsboro</option>
    <option value="Grandview">Grandview</option>
    <option value="Festus">Festus</option>
    <option value="R-7">R-7</option>
    <option value="Home-Schooled">Home-Schooled</option>
    <option value="Other School">Other School</option>
</select>

    <input type="text" id="newSchool"/>
    <input type="button" id="otherschool" value="Insert"/>
```

Comment: I LOVE the first jsfiddle solution but could not get it to work... Error with:  self.ul = self.inp.nextSibling; - Unable to get property 'nextSibling' of undefined or null reference

Comment: This works great for me and should be the right answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery helps:

```
$("select[name='school']").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val == 'notlisted') {
        $('input[name="otherschool"]').show();
    } else {
        $('input[name="otherschool"]').hide();
    }
}).change();
```

and then in HTML

```
<input type="text" name="otherschool" style="display:none" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another `<option>` field with value other, when the user selects it they are allowed to enter the school name in an input box.

Comment: That will do nothing but pass "Other" to the $_POST variable.

Comment: @user1628741 then you will know to check the provided input field for the school.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have an add button next to this drop down? It doesn't seem intuitive to have the entry at the end of a drop down. As a user I my not even expand the drop down just scroll through the current values.

Comment: I actually considered that.  I could put the add button next to the dropdown and embed it in the page with an iframe.  But then the page would have to be reloaded to repopulate the dropdown list and any changes in the total form would be lost.

Comment: Use js to show/hide the dropdown/fields instead... Simpler and more efficient (see my example even if this is not exa tly what you want)